# How do I move a folder and contained files in an external volume to another external volume using Terminal

Tags: terminal, external-disk

I have two drobos. I want to move a folder (called A) from one drobo name (Behemoth) to another drobo (Galactus) using Terminal (Mac). I have tried

```
ditto ~/Volumes/Behemoth/A /Volumes/Galactus/
```

but it says directory not found? Thank you.

Comment: If it wasn't just a typo (see my answer), please add the output of `ls -l /Volumes` to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the mount points are correct

```
ditto /Volumes/Behemoth/A /Volumes/Galactus/
```

should work (you had an extra `~` on the source side).

In case you want to *move* the data (as the text in your question implies)

```
mv /Volumes/Behemoth/A /Volumes/Galactus/
```

will work as well (or you just `rm -r /Volumes/Behemoth/A` after you've successfully copied with `ditto`).

Comment: This will copy the directory, not move it.

Comment: @Milliways Indeed :-) I was more focused on the error message the OP got.

Comment: Thank you! this really helped, yes I added an additional character that caused the issue! Thank you again!